# Integration by parts and $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, vector-analysis

Is well known in the literature the integration by parts formula for dealing with integrals under the form
$$
\int_{X} f_{x_i}  g dx,  
$$
where $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

I was wondering what is the situation now if we have a similar but not equal integral:

$$
\int_{X} |f_{x_i}| \cdot |  g| dx,  
$$
where $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

**Do you know if the same integration by parts formula follows ?**

When I was writing this question I saw that the product could be considered in the Lebesgue space $L^1$, thus, in the same spirit I was wondering what is the situation if now we consider the product in $L^p$, *i.e.* if we consider an integral given by:
$$
\int_{X} |f_{x_i}  g|^p dx, 
$$

**is there some known formula for dealing with this case ?**